# How to create multiple tables and store json data in each table

Tags: javascript, html, json

**Html Code**

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {


var dmJSON = "three.json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Answer + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.Views + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
 });

});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
<thead>


    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**JSON data**

```
{
"records": [
  {
    "Clue" : "First Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the first clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
  {
    "Clue" : "Second Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the second clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "15"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Third Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the third clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Fourth Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the fourth clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Fifth Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the fifth clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Sixth Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the sixth clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Seventh Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the seventh clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Eigth Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the eigth clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  },
    {
    "Clue" : "Nintht Clue",
    "Answer" : "Answer to the ninth clue",
    "Status" : "Rejected",
    "Views" : "10"
  }
]
}
```

From the above code the JSON data is stored in a single table. i want to store each record in different tables.There are 8 records so i want 8 tables with 1 record in each.
For ex: in the 1st table i want the first record to be stored (i.e First clue, Answer to the first clue, Rejected 10)
 Similarly in the second table i want to store the second record. How to do that?
Any solution to this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you please try this :

```
 HTML:
   <html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
        <script>

           $(function() { 
              var dmJSON = "three.json";
              $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
                  $.each(data.records, function(i, f) { 
                     var $table="<table border=1><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" +                                     f.Clue + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Answer + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.Views + "</td>" + "</tr></tbody></table>"
                     $("#entrydata").append($table)
                    }); 
                 });

               });
                    </script>
                </head> 
              <body> 
               <div class="wrapper">
                 <div class="profile">
                      <div id='entrydata'></div>
                  </div>
                 </div>

                </body>

                 </html>
```

Comment: This worked too ! Thank you but  i want 1 column and 4 rows.. 1st value in the 1st row, the next value in the next row.. How to do that ?

Comment: please replace script tag by this for 1 column and 4 rows :  <script>

$(function() {


var dmJSON = "three.json";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
     
      var $table="<table border=1><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>" + "</tbody></table>"
        $("#entrydata").append($table)
 });

});

});   </script>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render each record in separate table, then your best bet is to create table dynamically. For example like this:

```
$(function() {
    var dmJSON = "three.json";
    $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
            var table = '<table>';
            table += "<tr><td>" + f.Clue + "</td><td>" + f.Answer + "</td><td>" + f.Status + "</td><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>";
            table += "</table>";
            $('.profile').append(table);
        });
    });
});
```

But with multiple tables it's harder to properly align columns, not sure if this is what you need though.

**Demo:**  http://plnkr.co/edit/ffyaAN41Wlev6jY9OB93?p=preview

Comment: Hey ! Thank you so much. This is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a ton for answering immediately.. The code worked.

Comment: i want 1 column and 4 rows.. 1st value in the 1st row, the next value in the next row.. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Storing JSON data in multiple tables, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/Lcczwhmk/)

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        "records": [{
            "Clue": "First Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the first clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Second Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the second clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "15"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Third Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the third clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Fourth Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the fourth clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Fifth Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the fifth clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Sixth Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the sixth clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Seventh Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the seventh clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Eigth Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the eigth clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }, {
            "Clue": "Nintht Clue",
            "Answer": "Answer to the ninth clue",
            "Status": "Rejected",
            "Views": "10"
        }]
    }
    $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<table border='1'>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Answer + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Status + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.Views + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("body");
    });
});
```